# Where does the phrase "cheater caught, Peter red" come from?

Tags: expressions, phrase-origin, subcontinental-english

Growing up in Pakistan, I heard variations of either:

- Cheater caught, Peter red; or
- Cheater cock, Peter red

I assumed it was about a cocky boy named Peter who was either caught red-handed or turned red when caught.

Googling this phrase yields no relevant results. Has anyone else heard this phrase in Pakistan or India? Where might it come from?

Comment: I've never heard that in England. Could it possibly be related to Peter Parker aka Spiderman?

Comment: I’ve never heard it either, but if it is something you say when someone is caught cheating/lying/similar, it would make sense to use _Peter_ since it rhymes with _cheater_. Not sure where the cock might come into it, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Definition 2 could be relevant for cheaters, and the color could be accurate as well for those caught In the act:  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/peter

Comment: It’s a puzzle.  The starting point is that there is an expression ‘caught red handed’ meaning caught in the act of doing something wrong.  So you may have picked up a partial or garbled expression you heard.

Comment: Hmm, if that's a saying in Pakistan, or the direct translation of a saying, then it's an idiom.  Idioms are phrases where the meaning cannot be surmised from the words themselves.  As such, idioms don't translate, or translating them requires finding an idiom in the new language that means the same thing but isn't a direct translation, like the Portuguese idiom "falar pelos cotovelos" directly translates as "talk through one's elbows," which makes no sense to English speakers, but the English idiom "talk one's head off" does, which means the same thing.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman it's certainly not a translation of an Urdu saying in Pakistan, but an English phrase entirely. I suppose you're right that it's better asked on Pakistani forums, though.

Comment: Both phrases only show up here and nowhere else in a Google search, so maybe they're specific to the OP's family or friends, or a mishearing.

Comment: Probably closely related: "[Etymology of the word 'cheatercock'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/603896/etymology-of-the-word-cheatercock)."